# ionic2 Type 'any' is not a constructor function type

Tags: angular, ionic2

After I add QQSDK, when i run `ionic serve -l` error coming

[image]

And I checked, I find error
[image]

I think I have to import `IonicNativePlugin` to somewhere, but not sure where to put

This is what showing in terminal

[image]

UPDATE:

Here is my `ionic info`

[image]

update error

[image]

Thanks Younis Ar M.. problem solved. the problem is core version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating to the latest ionic native

```
npm uninstall -–save @ionic-native/core
npm install –-save @ionic-native/core@latest
```

Comment: Ok..I will try update now..but why here showing error in 'IonicNativePlugin', so no need to import is to somewhere?

Comment: whats the version of ionic-native in your dev dependencies ?

Comment: Newbie in ionic2, help me check is it got problem in my 'ionic info' please..thanks a lot

Comment: check in package.json   "@ionic-native/core": "[VERSION NUMBER]"

Comment: "ionic-native": "2.4.1"

Comment: can you make sure that you have updated @ionic-native/core. It should be >= '3.6.1'

Comment: Update got error showing.. I updated in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151577/discussion-between-younis-ar-m-and-yuyang-he).